# Preciso gerar um relatório pdf, a partir de uma div HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, jspdf

Sendo que quando o meu é gerado, o documento aparece como imagem e não com texto, como deveria. Como resolver este problema?

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#botaoImprimir').click(function() {
   var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4');
   doc.addHTML($('#divImagemPDF'), function() {

    doc.save("RelatórioExplainDB2.pdf");

   });

  });

 })
</script>
```

```html
 <!----------------------------->
 <!--------DIV RELATÓRIO-------->
 <!----------------------------->
 <div class="divForm" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="divCentralForm" id="divCentralForm" >
   <div class="divImagemPDF" id="divImagemPDF"
    style="background-color: white;width: 100%;">
    <p class="titleForm">PARECER TÉCNICO</p>
    <hr class="hrInicio">

    <div class="divRelatorioQualidade" id="relatorioQualidade"
     style="background-color: #e6e6e6; height: 500px; width: 100%;">
     <table border="1" class="tblRelatorioQualidade">
      <tr>
       <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bolder">RELATÓRIODE QUALIDE DE CÓDIGO DE DB2 STORED PROCEDURE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><b>SYSTEM DB2</b></td>
       <td>${ambiente}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><b>SCHEMA</b></td>
       <td>${schema}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><B>ELEMENTO</B></td>
       <td>${nomeProcedure}</td>
      </tr>
     </table>

     <div class="valorRecomendado">
      Maior TOTAL_COST do elemento = ${maiorTotalCost} <br> Valor
      recomendado = 1.0 <br> <br> Maior PROCMS do elemento =
      ${maiorPROCMS} <br> Valor recomendado = 1 <br>
     </div>
     <BR>
     <textarea class='areaTextParecerTecnico'
      id="areaTextParecerTecnico" rows="7" maxlength="1200"
      style="width: 75%; height: 250px;">
 TOTAL_COST: 
 ACCESSTYPE: 
 INDEXONLY: 
 PROCMS: </textarea>

     <!-- <div class="divParecer" id="divParecer" contenteditable="true">
      TOTAL_COST<BR> ACCESSTYPE<BR> INDEXONLY<BR> PROCMS<BR>
     </div> -->
     <BR>
    </div>

    <hr class="hrFinal">
   </div>

   <input class="btn btn-default botaoImprimir botaoForm" type="button"
    id="botaoImprimir" value="GERAR PDF" /> <input
    class="btn btn-default botaoFechar botaoForm" type="button"
    value="FECHAR" onclick="hideForm()" />
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi vc precisa que o PDF gerado seja Pesquisavel, no entanto o `addHTML` disponibilizado pela classe te da apenas uma foto da área que vc especificou, tornando impossível a seleção de texto, aparentemente ainda não ha opção de realizar isto na classe jsPDF, baseado nas minhas experiencias anteriores com pdf eu recomendo que use a classe mPDF, simples e intuitiva ela permite que vc gere PDF Pesquisavel.

Comment: vlw irmão, vou tentar aqui !!

Comment: de nada, se resolveu seu problema por favor marque a resposta como aceita

Comment: Então cara, eu tentei aqui e não resolveu.Pesquisei sobre o mPDF e vi que ele é mais utilizado no PHP, sendo meu "back" está em java. Não sei se tem uma forma de usar ele no java, se souber, aponte um exemplo por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Para funcionar como texto é necessário perceber que não vai ter impressa a pagina com mesma formatação e cores, isso só é possivel sendo uma imagem. uma alternativa é usar o plugin `autotable` que lhe permite controlar o layout e faz impressão como texto, o que já o torna pesquizavél.

Veja um exemplo aqui: [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/sereno/p5pcLqz2/)

```js
function printHTML() {

  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("table-content"));

  var header = function() {
   
    var header1 = document.getElementById("header1").innerHTML;

    doc.setFontSize(13);
    doc.setFontType("bold");
  doc.text(header1 , 20, 40);
    
    doc.setDrawColor(255,255,255,255);
    doc.setLineWidth(2);
    doc.line(20, 56, 555, 56); 
  };

  var options = {
   theme: "plain",  // 'striped', 'grid' or 'plain'
    beforePageContent: header,
    margin: {
      top: 80,
      left: 20
    },
    headerStyles: {
     font: "helvetica",
      textColor: 0,
      lineWidth: 0.5,
      halign: 'center', 
     valign: 'middle'
    },
    styles: {
      cellPadding: 3,
     fontSize: 10,
      font: "helvetica",
      lineWidth: 0
    }
  };

  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, options);
 
  doc.save("table.pdf");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.1.0/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p></p>
<button onclick="printHTML();">PDF</button>
<p></p>

<div id ='header1'>PARECER TÉCNICO</div>

<table id="table-content" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bolder">RELATÓRIODE QUALIDE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>SYSTEM DB2</b></td>
    <td>${ambiente}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>SCHEMA</b></td>
    <td>${schema}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><B>ELEMENTO</B></td>
    <td>${nomeProcedure}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```